# How to pass an array of function pointers as an argument?

Tags: arrays, c, arguments, function-pointers

I have an array of function pointers  `int (*oper_ptr[4])(int, int) = {add, sub, mul, divi};`  for the below functions which simply perform a standard operation on two passed integers:

```
int add(int num_a, int num_b); 
int sub(int num_a, int num_b); 
int mul(int num_a, int num_b); 
int divi(int num_a, int num_b);
```

What is the best way to pass this array into another function. I have tried:
`void polish(char* filename, int (*oper_ptr[4])(int, int))` with  for e.g., `oper_ptr[0](num_a, num_b);` to call the first function.

Comment: Use a typedef maybe?

Comment: cwonder, "have tried: `void polish(char* filename, int (*oper_ptr[4])(int, int))` with for e.g., `oper_ptr[0](num_a, num_b);` to call the first function." ==> OK, so what happened?  Rather than _describe_ code, _post_ the true code.  [MCVE]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you have done it works. But as always with function pointers, it's a bad idea to use them without typedef:

```
typedef int operation (int num_a, int num_b); 

void polish (char* filename, operation* op[4]);
```

Comment: Yes a useful idea, but _always_?   Standard C library does not follow this advice. e.g. `void qsort(void *base, size_t nmemb, size_t size, int (*compar)(const void *, const void *));`

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica The C standard library is filled to the brim with functions that have questionable or plain broken interfaces, so isn't something one should study for the purpose of learning proper API desin. Rather the contrary: a large part of stdio.h could be showcased as examples as some of the worst functions ever designed by mankind.